# Swift iOS notification sound problems

Tags: ios, swift, audio, push-notification

I'm currently working on a Swift project for an iOS app that involves receiving notifications. The app is designed to play different sounds based on a specific parameter when a notification arrives.
The correct behavior to follow is as follows.
There are two types of notifications in the project: start notifications and stop notifications.
Once the app receives a start notification it starts an audio player, the audio lasts X seconds but is looped by the player so it potentially lasts forever.
When the app receives the stop notification, the player stops and the sound stops.

This works great when the app is in the foreground.

When the phone is locked and therefore the app is closed, the sound that is heard is X seconds without the sound being repeated as it happens in the foreground.
Furthermore, it often happens that when the stop notification arrives, the player does not stop and continues until the end of X s time.

Does anyone have an idea of ​​how to put the loop to the sound of the notification with the phone locked and be sure that when the stop notification arrives the player stops?

Below I write the code that I used in my project. The sound stop works well on some devices while on others it doesn't even with the same iOS versions.

```
//
//  PushNotificationHandler.swift
//
//  Copyright © 2020 DuckMa Srl. All rights reserved.
//

import AVFoundation
import FirebaseMessaging
import Logging
import MediaPlayer
import UIKit

final class PushNotificationHandler: NSObject {
    let window: UIWindow
    fileprivate var timer: Timer?
    fileprivate var vibrationTimer: Timer?
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer
    private var audioPlayerFS: AVAudioPlayer
    private var audioPlayerDAE: AVAudioPlayer
    private var audioPlayerRC: AVAudioPlayer
    let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
    let updateFcmToken: (String) -> Void
    let didReceiveAlarm: (IncomingAlarm) -> Void
    let messaging: Messaging

    init(
        window: UIWindow,
        messaging: Messaging = Messaging.messaging(),
        updateFcmToken: @escaping (String) -> Void,
        didReceiveAlarm: @escaping (IncomingAlarm) -> Void
    ) {
        self.window = window
        self.messaging = messaging
        self.updateFcmToken = updateFcmToken
        self.didReceiveAlarm = didReceiveAlarm

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "allarme", ofType: "mp3"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer = player

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alarm FARMACO", ofType: "wav"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayerFS = player

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alarm DAE", ofType: "wav"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayerDAE = player

        guard
            let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alarm COVID", ofType: "wav"),
            let player = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
        else { preconditionFailure("Could not initialize player") }
        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayerRC = player

        super.init()

        self.messaging.delegate = self
    }

    deinit {
        Logger.App.info("Logger: deinit `PushNotificationHandler`")
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        vibrationTimer?.invalidate()
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.stop()
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        }
        if audioPlayerFS.isPlaying {
            audioPlayerFS.stop()
            audioPlayerFS.prepareToPlay()
        }
        if audioPlayerRC.isPlaying {
            audioPlayerRC.stop()
            audioPlayerRC.prepareToPlay()
        }
        if audioPlayerDAE.isPlaying {
            audioPlayerDAE.stop()
            audioPlayerDAE.prepareToPlay()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(
                withIdentifiers: [Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "com.duckma.prova"]
            )
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(
                withIdentifiers: [Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "com.duckma.prova"]
            )
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        }
        
    }
}

// MARK: - MessagingDelegate

extension PushNotificationHandler: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else { return }
        Logger.App.info("Logger: fcmToken \(fcmToken)")
        updateFcmToken(fcmToken)
    }
}

// MARK: - Alarm notification

extension PushNotificationHandler {
    func startWork(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], publishNotification: Bool = true) {
        for key in userInfo.keys {
            print("\(key) : \(userInfo[key]!)")
        }
        Logger.App.info("Logger: Start publishing notification")
        stopTimer()
        guard
            let alarmAction = (userInfo["action"] as? String).flatMap(
                IncomingAlarm.Action.init(rawValue:)
            ),
            let alarmId = userInfo["alarm_id"] as? String
        else { return }
        let title = (userInfo["title"] as? String) ?? ""
        let message = (userInfo["body"] as? String) ?? ""
        let alarmDuration = (userInfo["alarm_timeout"] as? Int) ?? 120
        let alarmType = (userInfo["type"] as? String) ?? ""
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let alarm = IncomingAlarm(id: alarmId, duration: alarmDuration, action: alarmAction, type: alarmType)
            self.didReceiveAlarm(alarm)
            if alarm.action == .stop {
                self.stopTimer()
                return
            }
            if publishNotification {
                self.publishNotification(title: title, message: message, type: alarmType)
            }

            if publishNotification {
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 9, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
                    Logger.App.info("Logger: rescheduling at \(Date())")
                    self?.publishNotification(title: title, message: message, type: alarmType)
                }
                self.vibrationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.5, repeats: true) { _ in
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func publishNotification(title: String, message: String, type: String) {
        Logger.App.info("Logger: Publishing notification")

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(
                .playAndRecord, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker]
            )
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

            volumeView.setVolume(1) {
                if self.volumeView.superview == nil {
                    self.window.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self.volumeView)
                }

                self.audioPlayerRC.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                self.audioPlayerDAE.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                self.audioPlayerFS.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                self.audioPlayer.setVolume(1, fadeDuration: 0.5)
                switch type {
                case "FS":
                    self.audioPlayerFS.numberOfLoops = -1
                    self.audioPlayerFS.play()
                case "DAE":
                    self.audioPlayerDAE.numberOfLoops = -1
                    self.audioPlayerDAE.play()
                case "NC":
                    self.audioPlayerDAE.numberOfLoops = -1
                    self.audioPlayerDAE.play()
                case "RC":
                    self.audioPlayerRC.numberOfLoops = -1
                    self.audioPlayerRC.play()
                default:
                    self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
                    self.audioPlayer.play()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            Logger.App.info("Logger: Audio Session error: \(error)")
        }

        let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notification.title = title
        notification.body = message

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "com.duckma.prova",
            content: notification,
            trigger: trigger
        )
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            guard error == nil else { return }
        }
    }
}

extension PushNotificationHandler: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // MARK: notifica ricevuta quando app in foreground
        let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        if state == .background || state == .inactive {
            // background

            completionHandler([.badge, .banner, .list, .sound,])
        } else if state == .active {
            // foreground
            let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
            let alarm_id =
                (userInfo["alarm_id"] as? String) ?? (userInfo["gcm.notification.alarm_id"] as? String)
            let action = (userInfo["action"] as? String)?.uppercased() ?? "START"
            if let alarmId = alarm_id {
                startWork(
                    userInfo: [
                        "action": action,
                        "alarm_id": alarmId,
                        "title": notification.request.content.title,
                        "body": notification.request.content.body,
                        "type": notification.request.content.userInfo["type"] as! String,
                    ],
                    publishNotification: true
                )
            }
        }
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // MARK: notifica ricevuta quando app in background
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        let alarm_id =
            (userInfo["alarm_id"] as? String) ?? (userInfo["gcm.notification.alarm_id"] as? String)
        let action = (userInfo["action"] as? String)?.uppercased() ?? "START"
        if let alarmId = alarm_id {
            startWork(
                userInfo: [
                    "action": action,
                    "alarm_id": alarmId,
                    "title": response.notification.request.content.title,
                    "body": response.notification.request.content.body,
                ],
                publishNotification: false
            )
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension MPVolumeView {
    func setVolume(_ volume: Float, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let slider = subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01) {
            slider?.value = volume
            completion()
        }
    }
}

// http://andrewmarinov.com/building-an-alarm-app-on-ios/
private extension MPVolumeView {
    var volumeSlider: UISlider? {
        showsRouteButton = false
        showsVolumeSlider = false
        isHidden = true
        let slider = subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider
        slider?.isContinuous = false
        return slider
    }
}
```